# How to use D3 inside a ui-view state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

So I have an angular application that is using ui-router.  Say I want to display a bar graph inside `div.wtf`like so:

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view ></div>
```

**state1.html**

```
<div class="wtf"></div>
```

**js:**

```
var dataset = [5,3,2,2,10];
d3.select('.wtf').selectAll('div')
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append('div')
.attr('class', 'bar')
.style('height', function (d) {
  return d * 5 + 'px';
});
```

Does the js have to be in a controller?  if so how to I make sure the document is ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with custom directives. It gives access to the DOM without junking up your controller.

```
app.directive('bindDeeThreeStuff', function($window){
  var d3 = $window.d3;

  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var d3Elem = d3.select(elem[0]);

    scope.$watch(attrs.bindDeeThreeStuff, function(val) {
      d3Elem.selectAll('.bar').data(val)
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .style('height', function(d) {
          return d * 5
        });
    });
  };
});
```

And in your view:

```
<div bind-dee-three-stuff="myData"></div>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.myData = [10,20,30,40,50];
```

#### Edit: Example

[Here's a quick example of a simple directive that binds data with d3](http://jsbin.com/seqen/1/edit).